# Why my RESTs not issued in parallel over HTTP2?

Tags: angular, google-chrome, http2

I have an Angular website, which needs to send REST requests to the backend. In order to get required data faster, I want to leverage a HTTP/2 protocol, which allows multiple parallel requests over single connection.

This is my Angular 11 code (typescript), sending 40 requests in loop:

```
const observables: Observable<RecordingStepScreenshot>[] = [];

const endpoint = ...;

for (let i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    observables.push(this.http.get<RecordingStepScreenshot>(endpoint));
}

forkJoin(observables).subscribe((result) => {
    console.log('execution of all calls has been finished');
});
```

In the snipped above, I issuing in parallel 40 HTTP "get" requests. I using "forkJoin" to wait for completion of all observables.

I was expecting all of them will be issued and completed in about the same time (in parallel).
However, in a browser (Chrome 96) I see that requests issued one after other, in kind of waterfall manner:

[image]

What do I missing?

Comment: Browsers have a maximum number of requests that they will run simultaneously...

Comment: @Carsten this is correct, but relevant only for HTTP 1. I saw in my eyes few years ago how multiple (dozens) static resources downloaded in parallel over http 2. however, i didnt tried at that time to issue Ajax calls. Also, even over http1 browser able to issue bulks of 6-8 requests, but here i see only one at time

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone will find it useful:

As I found in some other SO answer, when Chrome see multiple requests to the same destination (this is what I did in my sample) - it waits for previous request to complete in order to save next calls. This behavior can be altered by disabling cache (cache no store header). Sending multiple requests to different destinations issues all requests in parallel, as expected.

Comment: I am also facing same issue in angular 8/12 also.
I ahve used forkjoin to call 3 apis parallelly. But still calls are going sequentially and waiting for others to complete.

const observables: any[] = [];    observables.push(this.leaderboardAgentDetailsService.getRewardsPoints().pipe(catchError(e => of(''))));
    observables.push(this.leaderboardAgentDetailsService.getPursuitsLevel().pipe(catchError(e => of(error))));
    observables.push(this.leaderboardAgentDetailsService.getTrivia().pipe(catchError(e => of(error))));
    forkJoin(observables).subscribe(
      (resp: any) => {

Comment: What i saw is after setting headers all calls are Not-working  as parallelly. Once remove request headers, then working properly